# Is there a way to transform state-space matrices $A$ and $C$ into canonical forms for stochastic systems?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

I have a stochastic MIMO state space system as follows:
\begin{align*}
x_{k+1} &= Ax_k + w_k\\
y_k &= Cx_k + v_k
\end{align*}

I want to find the transformation matrix $T$ for converting $A$ to observable 
canonical form $A_o$ using relation
\begin{equation*}
A_o = T^{-1} A T
\end{equation*} 
and with that, $C$ gets transformed to $C_o = CT$. I tried using MATLAB 
**canon** function, but it needs the knowledge of $B$ matrix. If $B$ is set to zero matrix then **canon** throws out an error. Is there any 
way to get the transformation matrix $T$ without the need for matrix $B$?

Any reference would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It seems in your system the matrix $B$ is just zero. From this page https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/State-Space_Equations, the $B$ matrix is the control matrix, which "determines how the system input affects the state change. If the state change is not dependent on the system input, then B will be the zero matrix. "

Comment: Edited the question to incorporate your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observer forms do not depend on the matrix B. Pick any.

Whether the system is stochastic or deterministic isn't important from this point of view.

Note however that there isn't one form that can be called THE canonical form for multivariable systems. The method you use may pick one, but there's a degree of freedom. It has to do with observability indices.